# Is there any way to modify tracking.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, shipment-tracking

When we choose one of the option below, the field 'title' automatically filled with selected value from carrier options.

I want to do the same for 'number' field, it would be filled with something when I choose my custom carrier. Is there any way to modify this tracking form? If yes, how?
[image: tracking form]

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look in the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml`, tracking.phtml is used several times. If this change is for a module then create a layout file '*yourmodule*.xml' and enable it from your config file. Otherwise name it 'local.xml'. It's contents will have to be an update something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
        <reference name="shipment_tracking">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>your/new/tracking.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
</layout>
```

Also if you want to minimize number of copypasted layout statements you can use 
`<update handle="handle_name" />` inside different controller action handles. For example:

```
<my_handle_name>
    <reference name="shipment_tracking"> 
        <action method="setTemplate"> 
            <template>your/new/tracking.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </reference> 
</my_handle_name> 
<adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
    <update handle="my_handle_name"/>
</adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
```